# Using onEdit trigger on data that is uploaded from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have one spreadsheet that takes data from an onEdit trigger, and inserts it into a new spreadsheet. Now, I am trying to get this new spreadsheet to send an email when that data is inserted from the other spreadsheet based on certain values.

I have tried a ton of different combinations hoping to get something to work, but to no luck. My project trigger error rate is going down, so the function is working. It just isn't populating an email and sending the data. I am not sure if my If statement is wrong or what is happening.

```
function sendEmail(){

  var recipientList = "EMAIL";
  var emailSubject = "Great Test Email";
  var senderName = "EmailSender";
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var emailTable = "<table> <tr><th>|| Control ID ||</th> <th>Significance ||</th> <th>Control Owner ||</th> <th> Control Certifier ||</th> <th>Next IA Testing Date ||</th> <th>Most Recent IA Test Results ||</th> <th> Test Date ||</th> <th>Test Results ||</th> <th>IA Control Conclusion ||</th> </tr>";
  var subject = 'UPDATE on: '+ s.getSheetName();     
  var i = 2;
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();


  var controlID = s.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
  var significance = s.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
  var controlOwner = s.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
  var controlCertifier = s.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
  var nextIATestingStartDate =  Utilities.formatDate(s.getRange(i, 6).getValue(), "America/Los_Angeles", "MMM-dd-yyyy"); // Format that date/timestamp 
  var mostRecentIATestResultsConclusion = s.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
  var TestDate = s.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
  var TestResults = s.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
  var IAControlConclusion = s.getRange(i, 10).getValue();


  emailTable += "<tr><td>" + controlID + "</td> <td>" + significance + "</td> <td>" + controlOwner + "</td> <td>" + controlCertifier + "</td> <td>" + nextIATestingStartDate + "</td> <td>" + mostRecentIATestResultsConclusion + "</td> <td>" + TestDate + "</td> <td>" + TestResults + "</td> <td>" + IAControlConclusion + "</td> </tr>";
  emailTable += "</table>";      

  if (controlCertifier === 'FILTER') {

     MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: recipientList,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: emailTable
  }); 
}
}
```

Comment: You have two declarations for i `var i = 2;
     var lastRow = s.getLastRow();

     for (var i; i <= lastRow; i++) {` and the second leaves i initialized to undefined.

Comment: In `if (Certifier === 'FILTER' === true) {` Certifier is undefined.  It doesn't look like you even tried to run this in the debugger.

Comment: Most, if not all, of the variables in this `emailTable += "<tr><td>" + control + "</td> <td>" + significance + "</td><td>" + owner + "</td> <td>" + Certifier + "</td> <td>" + TestingStartDate + "</td> <td>" + TestResultsConclusion + "</td> <td>" + KTestDate + "  </td>  <td>" + TestResults + "</td> <td>" + Conclusion + "</td> </tr>";
  ` are undefined.  We're here to help not to write your code for you.

Comment: I hadn't finished editing the draft before I hit submit oops. I have made the edit to the draft I am working on. Ok, I see the var i = 2 and the var i is defined twice. I have every variable that I call defined correctly so that isn't an issue.(I think) That was where I was editing then I hit submit to soon. When I run my daily notifier it works. But when I make one to send immediately it doesn't send the email. It logs the trigger but doesn't send the email. That's what I am looking for help on...

Comment: What is controlCertifier supposed to be to send an email?

Comment: A name of a person in the cell/column. I just removed it for confidentiality.

Comment: So this `if (controlCertifier === 'FILTER' === true) {`  should probably be this `if (controlCertifier === 'FILTER') {` What do you think?  or perhaps just `if(controlCertifier)`

Comment: I don't need === true? Let me try it out.

Comment: Please update your code so that we can know where you're at.

Comment: Ok, I updated my code to take out === TRUE. I am not getting an update on the execution or the email.

Comment: Okay so it's time to go into your script editor and single step through the program to figure out what's not working.

Comment: Cooper, I think I figured out my issue, when I defined var i = 2 I am defining row 2 correct in the rest of my variables? and it is appending a new row at the bottom every time it gets entered. So I think for the row I need to define the variable as the most recently updated row. Does that sound right?

Comment: Update: Never mind It didn't work I will go look at my code and get back to you. This is what I tried to write instead     var i = lastRow+1;

Comment: @Hippo Hi. Did you resolve your problem or are you still looking for assistance?

Comment: @Tedinoz I resolved my problem! I instead of using the onEdit trigger switched it to a time stamp and ran a search query every 10 min and 24 hours for notifications. I will post the solution. onEdit doesn't work for automated edit/insert functions which I found a post about on the gas class page. So I redesigned it to search within time constraints instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found. I learned about loops and then instead of using the onEdit to send an email I just made a daily sender(it could be as frequent as you want) and set it based on the time stamp that it's logged at. So if the row was inserted within the last 214 hours then log it and send the email. This compiles it all instead of sending it one at a time. I felt like this was a better solution than the question I originally posted.

Excuse my poor set up I am still learning! Thanks for everyone's help.

```
function dailyEmail() {

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var recipientList = "EMAIL";
    var digestFrequency = 1.0;
    var emailSubject = 'Changes were made to: '+ s.getSheetName();   
    var senderName = "Email Sender";
    var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
    var i = 2;
    var date = new Date(); 
    var entriesCounter = 1;

  var emailTable = '<table> <tr><th style = "width: 200px" bgcolor = "#aed1e8"> Control ID </th> <th style = "width: 200px" bgcolor = "#aed1e8">Significance </th> <th style = "width: 500px" bgcolor = "#aed1e8">Control Description </th> <th style = "width: 200px" bgcolor = "#aed1e8">Control Owner </th><th style = "width: 200px" bgcolor = "#aed1e8"> Control Certifier </th> <th style = "width: 200px" bgcolor = "#aed1e8">Next IA Testing Date </th> <th style = "width: 200px" bgcolor = "#aed1e8">Most Recent IA Test Results Conclusion</th> <th style = "width: 200px" bgcolor = "#aed1e8"> Test Date </th> <th style = "width: 200px" bgcolor = "#aed1e8">Test Results </th> <th style = "width: 200px" bgcolor = "#aed1e8">IA Control Conclusion </th><th style = "width: 200px" bgcolor = "#aed1e8">Column Updated </th> </tr>';

    for (var i; i <= lastRow; i++) {

      var iaTestDate = new Date( s.getRange(i, 7).getValue());
      var rowDate = new Date(s.getRange(i, 1).getValue()); // your date from API         

//Time is standard set to milliseconds
      var t1 = date.getTime(),
          t2 = rowDate.getTime();
//Math to find the difference in days from the current date to the date that each row was edited or changed
      var diffInDays = Math.floor((t1-t2)/(24*3600*1000));// 24*3600*1000 is milliseconds in a day
      if (diffInDays <= digestFrequency) {
        entriesCounter++;

        var controlID = s.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
        var significance = s.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
        var controlName = s.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
        var controlOwner = s.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
        var controlCertifier = s.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
        var nextIATestingStartDate = Utilities.formatDate(iaTestDate, "America/Los_Angeles", "MMM-dd-yyyy"); // Format that date/timestamp 
        var mostRecentIATestResultsConclusion = s.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
        var TestDate = s.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
        var TestResults = s.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
        var IAControlConclusion = s.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
        var headerColumn = s.getRange(i, 12).getValue();    

//builds the table data for the email   
        emailTable += "<tr><td style = 'width: 200px' bgcolor = '#F8F8F8'>" + controlID + "</td> <td style = 'width: 200px' bgcolor = '#F8F8F8'>" + significance + "</td> <td style = 'width: 500px' bgcolor = '#F8F8F8'>" + controlName + "</td> <td style = 'width: 200px' bgcolor = '#F8F8F8'>" + controlOwner + "</td> <td style = 'width: 200px' bgcolor = '#F8F8F8'>" + controlCertifier + "</td> <td style = 'width: 200px' bgcolor = '#F8F8F8'>" + nextIATestingStartDate + "</td> <td style = 'width: 200px' bgcolor = '#F8F8F8'>" + mostRecentIATestResultsConclusion + "</td> <td style = 'width: 200px' bgcolor = '#F8F8F8'>" + TestDate + "</td> <td style = 'width: 200px' bgcolor = '#F8F8F8'>" + TestResults + "</td> <td style = 'width: 200px' bgcolor = '#F8F8F8'>" + IAControlConclusion + "</td><td style = 'width: 200px' bgcolor = '#F8F8F8'>" + headerColumn + "</td> </tr>";
      }      
    }

      emailTable += "</table>";

      if (entriesCounter == 1) {

        emailTable = "<b>No changes were made since the previous report.</b>";     
      }

     var htmlBody = "Hello, <br><br> This is an automated email sent between 6-7am. <br> <br> The Following changes have been made within the past 24 hours.<br><br>" + emailTable + '<br><br> <a href = "URL"><b>Visit the Google Sheet for this e-mail here</b></a>';
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipientList, emailSubject, '', {
        to: recipientList,
        name: senderName,
        htmlBody: htmlBody,
        cc: recipientList
      });   
      }
```